# Kubernetes events for pod termination or job completion

Tags: kubernetes

Our application runs jobs on Kubernetes.
We are currently querying kubernetes to give feedback to the users about the statuses of jobs and once a job is completed also want to provide them the job (pod) logs. This happens often, eg every 30s.
We have such high amount of jobs now, that this pod querying and handling the information takes too long.

It would be great to be informed about kubernetes events: a pod is pending, scheduled, pulling, running, succeeded/failed. Not sure what is the best way to get these events in our application, but the main questions here is:

**Is there any event that a pod is terminated (successfully or in failure) or that a job is completed?**

If this does not exist, is there a workaround to get to know whether a pod or job is terminated (so that we can go fetch the pod logs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kubectl get events` provides events happening in the cluster. For advanced scenarios you can check [kubewatch](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch).

Kubewatch is a Kubernetes watcher that currently publishes notification to available collaboration hubs/notification channels. Run it in your k8s cluster, and you will get event notifications through webhooks.

Another option would be to add a handler in preStop which sends an event before the pod/job is terminated

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers

Comment: Thanks you. I am aware of this, but there is no pod termination or job completed event. At least not in my version of k8s (1.13)

Comment: After investigating further:
Kubewatch (and botkube) do not work on kubernetes events. That's what I assumed before.
Instead, they watch the kubernetes api.
Kubewatch is inactive and both Kubewatch and botkube are not really customizable. Instead, I think for our use case it's better to write our own watch (and possibly informer). Python examples for this are: https://github.com/polyaxon/ocular/blob/master/ocular or https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/pod_namespace_watch.py